# Is there any comprehensive classification of thinking style?

Tags: thought

I see many thinking styles,
inductive thought, deductive thought, critical thinking, convergent thinking, divergent thinking, dominant thinking, and so on.

but is there any comprehensive classification of thinking styles? then we can glance over all of them.

Comment: Most of these terms are from everyday language and are not the focus of cognitive science research. Also keep in mind the distinction between types of reasoning, e.g., syllogistic, describing a characteristic of an individual, e.g., likes to think hard, and words describing a psychological process, e.g., reasoning.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  I agree with @CameronBrick - I am not convinced that the examples provided are all of the same *kind*.  There are inferences (inductive, deductive), skills (critical, creative), subsets (dominant, secondary) ... in contrast, [thinking styles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_style) usually refer to a personality trait (convergent, divergent are examples of this).  Can you please provide a reference that describes how the examples you provided are connected?  Otherwise, I'm afraid this question may be too broad and open-ended for this forum.